# Backup por mysqldump linha por linha

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Estou usando o mysqldump para exportar somente os dados do meu banco, porém ao exportar, ele mostra apenas uma linha com todos os inserts. É possível fazer um insert de registro por linha? Ex:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA() VALUES();
INSERT INTO TABELA() VALUES();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar este comando:

```
mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE
```

Esta resposta foi encontrada neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12439368/6762369

Comment: Show, funcionou....Obrigado.

Comment: De nada Amigo!!